# Add default filter text in selectCheckBoxMenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How can I add a default filter text for a selectCheckBoxMenu in PrimeFaces? I didn't find any attribute. It looks like the older versions has a "filterText" attribute, but I cannot find it in 5.3.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this, it works for me:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.ui-selectcheckboxmenu-filter-container').children(':first').val('initialvalue');
        $('.ui-selectcheckboxmenu-filter-container').children(':first').keyup();
    });
</script>
```

Put last in xhtml. If the initial value must come from a bean use i.e.

```
$('.ui-selectcheckboxmenu-filter-container').children(':first').val('#{testBean.initialValue}');
```

If you have many selectCheckBoxMenu's in the page you can adjust the selector and add an id or class.